# Including other *.o files with Cabal

Tags: haskell, cabal

I'm building a simple library that wraps some parts of Qt.  I want to be able to use Qt's `qmake` configuration system to find the Qt libraries on the given system, etc, to build the c wrapper code.  I can get this to work and produce a *.o file, no problem.

But how can I get cabal to include this *.o file in the *.a it generates?  I assume I'll have to write a custom Setup.hs to make it work, but reading over the Cabal library documentation I don't see an obvious way to do it.

On #haskell someone suggested that I could use postBuild to add files to the *.a after it is generated, but even then how do I get the path to the generated *.a from inside postBuild?

Comment: If memory serves me, you should be able to find an example of this in the Intel-aes package.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson close, that package seems to be using a seperately-distributed dynamic library to work around this issue.